# Configurable Products: Update Media Gallery - Not Just Base Image

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, media, configurable-swatches

I feel what I am trying to do is simple, but cannot find a still-supported method of doing this.

I would like to have the entire media-gallery update to the images listed on the associated SKU (via attribute selection). Instead, it only updates the base image and continues to show any other images in the parent configurable product's gallery.

This seems to be an open issue for M2, but their temporary fix (see below) is not working for me.

```
<!-- Insert this code on your theme's ../etc/view.xml: -->

  <vars module="Magento_ConfigurableProduct">
    <var name="change_only_base_image">false</var>
  </vars>
  <vars module="Magento_Swatches">
    <var name="change_only_base_image">false</var>
  </vars>
```

I see some old configurable swatch extensions that are no longer supported or in development ever since 1.9 was released with Configurable Swatches as a standard.

Yes I have my attributes selected and enabled as configurable swatches - so please don't ask.

Is there a way to rewrite the media.js that displays the gallery in such a way as to look at selected attributes and refresh the gallery? Any help is appreciated!